# Control structure in sxw

Tags: odoo

I'm using `openerp` Report designer on `OpenOffice` to modify an existing invoice report.

I would like to use structure control to print different "terms & conditions" regarding the language of the partner.

How do I use structure control in `sxw document` ?

Will this be fine? :

```
[[if o.partner_id.lang=='English':"some text" else:"some other text"]]
```

Comment: Why not use OpenERP translation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `[[o.partner_id.lang=='English' and "some text" or "some other text"]]`

it actually takes python codes.